# State not updating correctly with get request from API

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-state

I am making two api GET requests, and with both I would like the state to update. For some reason it is only updating with the values from the first GET request.

I have tried using the spread operator to update the state and add in new values to current state (categories) from the GET requests.

```
axios // first get request
  .get(
    "LINK_TO_API"
  )
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.categories,
      categories: res.data.data
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
axios // second get request
  .get(
    "LINK_TO_API"
  )
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.categories,
      categories: res.data.data
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

I am currently getting 10 values from first GET request and would like to get the total of 20 values when I map through categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will never get 20 values, due to are not appending values, you just are overwriting categories values in each call.

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state.categories,
  categories: res.data.data
});
```

Here `categories: res.data.data` is being overwrited.

Just modify your code to:

```
 axios
  .get(
    "LINK_TO_API"
  )
  .then(res => {
    this.setState((state) => ({
      ...state,
      categories: [...state.categories, ...res.data.data]
    }));
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that categories is an `array`, you are overriding one array with another array.

In the code below, i am always returning a new array, and concating the new array with the previous array.

```
axios // first get request
  .get('LINK_TO_API')
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      categories: [...this.state.categories, ...res.data.data]
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
axios // second get request
  .get('LINK_TO_API')
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      categories: [...this.state.categories, ...res.data.data]
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Just a tip, you need to do [...res.data.data]

Comment: @F.bernal of course, it was a mistake. now correct (:

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your spread operator is wrong, you have to wrap it into array `categories: [...this.state.categories, ...res.data.data]`. Also I advice you to wait all your post loaded and then set them to state:

```
Promise.all([axios.get('LINK_TO_API'), axios.get('LINK_TO_API_2')])
    .then(allYourPosts => {
        this.setState({ /* set it to state */ });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: why wait for all the calls? that only has the sense when you need 'n' results, concretely, in this case, it is not needed. If call to API_2 takes 60 seconds why it needs to wait to show results from API_1?

Comment: Good point with second call, I just wanted to avoid blinking from multiple rerenders.